# Problem in doing Add Web Reference (http://.../service.asmx)

Tags: web-services

I am trying to Add a Web Reference to http//.../service.asmx file in my project.

1. First it gives me an error:

"...
Unable to download following files from:
http://.../service.asmx?wsdl
Do you want to skip these files and continue
..."

When i click 'Yes', the proxy gets created with .disco and other reference files, but does not adds .wsdl file.

2. Other option i tried, i used http//.../service.asmx?wsdl to add web reference. In this case, i dont get any error, but the proxy gets added with .wsdl and reference files, but it does not adds .disco file.

Can someone help me on why this is happening? I thought, adding web reference to .asmx should add everything under the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain the service is running. Right-click the .ASMX file in Solution Explorer and use "View in Browser". *Then* try the "Add Web Reference".

Comment: The service is already hosted on the server and when i test in the browser it is working fine.

Comment: Do you actually _care_ about the .disco file? Does it otherwise create a valid proxy?

Comment: I am actually getting error when adding web reference using http://..service.asmx, that it cannot find the wsdl file. What could be the issue in that?